# Using strcmp() in order to compare user input character array with an array of strings in C

Tags: c, strcmp

```
/*This is a program to generate notes of major scale in C programing given WS,WS,HS,WS,WS,WS */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){

    int i = 0; 
    int totalIntervals = 11;
    
    char *notes[12] = {"A", "A#", "B", "C","C#","D","D#","E","F","F#","G","G#"};
    char pickedNote[2] ;
    
    for(i=0;i<12;++i){
        printf("Your notes are  %s\n",notes[i]);
    }
    
    printf("Please type in a note\n");
    scanf("%s",pickedNote);
    printf("Your note is %s\n",pickedNote);

    for(i=0;i<12;++i)
    {
        int truth = strcmp(pickedNote,&notes[i]);
        printf("%d\n",&truth);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT SHOULD LOOK LIKE(FOR EXAMPLE IF I TYPE A)

```
Your note is A
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

BUT I am getting

```
Your note is A
-1614868988
-1614868988
-1614868988
-1614868988
-1614868988
-1614868988
-1614868988
-1614868988
-1614868988
-1614868988
-1614868988
-1614868988
```

Getting this correct will help me to find the index position so that I may apply the formula correctly.

Comment: `int truth = (strcmp(pickedNote, notes[i]) == 0) ? 1 : 0;`

Comment: `printf("%d\n",&truth);` --> `printf("%d\n",truth);` You want to print the value _inside_ of `truth` and _not_ the _address_ of the variable `truth`. If you compiled with warnings (e.g. `-Wall`) this `printf` would have been flagged by the compiler.

Comment: You write out of bounds with the `scanf`. If using this horrible function, always use a length modifier and make sure the buffer is big enough

Comment: `pickedNote` needs to be at least three `char`s long to hold up to two characters plus the terminating `NUL`; you only allocated two `char`s. This assumes the user doesn't pass invalid input of course, which, thank to using unmodified `scanf` with code `%s`, they can do trivially and write *massively* out of bounds if they want.

Comment: To be totally safe (e.g.): `char pickedNote[100]; fgets(pickedNote,sizeof(pickedNote),stdin); pickedNote[strcspn(pickedNote,"\n")] = 0;` instead of the `scanf`

Comment: Not to mention invoking *Undefined Behavior* attempting to print a pointer address with `%d`.

Comment: Enable and read compiler warnings. That way you don't have to waste time chasing bugs that the compiler already found and told you about. [What compiler options are recommended for beginners learning C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/282565)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the refactored code. It is annotated with the bugs and fixes:

```
// This is a program to generate notes of major scale in C programing given
// WS,WS,HS,WS,WS,WS

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main(void)
{

    int i = 0;
// NOTE/BUG: unused variable
#if 0
    int totalIntervals = 11;
#endif

    char *notes[12] = { "A", "A#", "B", "C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#",
        "G", "G#" };
// NOTE/BUG: too small to contain a string of length 2 (needs space for \0)
#if 0
    char pickedNote[2];
#else
    char pickedNote[100];
#endif

    for (i = 0; i < 12; ++i) {
        printf("Your notes are  %s\n", notes[i]);
    }

    printf("Please type in a note\n");
// NOTE/BUG: this is unsafe -- no check for length of pickedNote being exceeded
#if 0
    scanf("%s", pickedNote);
#else
    fgets(pickedNote,sizeof(pickedNote),stdin);
    pickedNote[strcspn(pickedNote,"\n")] = 0;
#endif
    printf("Your note is %s\n", pickedNote);

    for (i = 0; i < 12; ++i) {
// NOTE/BUG: value is inverse of what is needed
// NOTE/BUG: &notes[i] is wrong (as notes is a _pointer_ array)
#if 0
        int truth = strcmp(pickedNote, &notes[i]);
#else
        int truth = (strcmp(pickedNote, notes[i]) == 0);
#endif

// NOTE/BUG: we want the contents of truth and _not_ its address (and trying
// to print an address with "%d" (vs. "%p") is UB)
// NOTE/BUG: this would have been flagged (by the compiler) if compiled with
// warnings enabled (the `-Wall` command line option)
#if 0
        printf("%d\n", &truth);
#else
        printf("%d\n", truth);
#endif
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

In the above code I've used `cpp` conditionals to denote old vs. new code:

```
#if 0
// old code
#else
// new code
#endif

#if 1
// new code
#endif
```

---

Here is the program output:

```
Your notes are  A
Your notes are  A#
Your notes are  B
Your notes are  C
Your notes are  C#
Your notes are  D
Your notes are  D#
Your notes are  E
Your notes are  F
Your notes are  F#
Your notes are  G
Your notes are  G#
Please type in a note
A
Your note is A
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

---

Here is the final cleaned up code (I ran the above through `unifdef -k` and removed the NOTE comments):

```
// This is a program to generate notes of major scale in C programing given
// WS,WS,HS,WS,WS,WS

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main(void)
{

    int i = 0;

    char *notes[12] = { "A", "A#", "B", "C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#",
        "G", "G#" };
    char pickedNote[100];

    for (i = 0; i < 12; ++i) {
        printf("Your notes are  %s\n", notes[i]);
    }

    printf("Please type in a note\n");
    fgets(pickedNote,sizeof(pickedNote),stdin);
    pickedNote[strcspn(pickedNote,"\n")] = 0;
    printf("Your note is %s\n", pickedNote);

    for (i = 0; i < 12; ++i) {
        int truth = (strcmp(pickedNote, notes[i]) == 0);

        printf("%d\n", truth);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> Sir in this part "pickedNote[strcspn(pickedNote,"\n")] = 0;" we are looking for the first instance of the newline escape character and replacing that index of the array with a null terminator is this correct to assume. By thank you for your prompt and descriptive response. –
> Rudy F

Yes, that is correct. It is an idiomatic way to strip the newline after an `fgets`.

Another way would be to use the GNU extension `strchrnul` function:

```
*strchrnul(pickedNote,'\n') = 0;
```

But, that isn't totally portable and requires that we do: `#define _GNU_SOURCE` before any `#include` statements.

Perhaps the simplest [and fastest] method is to use `strchr`:

```
char *cp = strchr(pickedNote,'\n');
if (cp != NULL)
    *cp = 0;
```

Comment: Sir in this part "pickedNote[strcspn(pickedNote,"\n")] = 0;" we are looking for the first instance of the newline escape character and replacing that index of the array with a null terminator is this correct to assume. By thank you for your prompt and descriptive response.

Comment: @RudyF. Yes, that is correct. I've updated my answer to show other ways to strip a newline.