# Segmentation Fault when attempting to use variable "i" to access a certain element in an array of strings in C programming

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

This is the code for running the Major scale program. The debugging using [gdb](/questions/tagged/gdb) is shown after the code. I am new to using pointers and allocating memory and what not.

```
// This is a program to generate a major scale based upon user input in C
// programming using formula WS WS HS WS WS WS

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main()
{

    int j = 0;
    int i = 0;
    // This tells you which turn you are on on turns 0,1,3,4,5,6 i will be
    // added by 2 and on turn 2 i will be added by 1
    int t = 0;

    char *notes[12] = {
        "A", "A#", "B", "C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#"
    };

    char pickedNote[100];

    for (i = 0; i < 12; ++i) {
        printf("Your notes are  %s\n", notes[i]);
    }

    printf("Please type in a note\n");
    fgets(pickedNote, sizeof(pickedNote), stdin);
    pickedNote[strcspn(pickedNote, "\n")] = 0;
    printf("Your note is %s\n", pickedNote);

    for (i = 0; i < 12; ++i) {
        int notePositionTester = (strcmp(pickedNote, notes[i]) == 0);

        if (notePositionTester == 1) {
            int notePosition = i;

            printf("Your note is in position %d\n", notePosition);
        }
        else;

    }

    printf("%s\n", notes[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the text version of the dubugging

```
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from ./a.out...
(gdb) ls
Undefined command: "ls".  Try "help".
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/rudy/Documents/C/MusicTheoryPractice/MajorScaleNotes/a.out
```

Here is our program promt and printouts

```
Your notes are  A
Your notes are  A#
Your notes are  B
Your notes are  C
Your notes are  C#
Your notes are  D
Your notes are  D#
Your notes are  E
Your notes are  F
Your notes are  F#
Your notes are  G
Your notes are  G#
Please type in a note
G
Your note is G
Your note is in position 10
```

From this point forward is our debugging output:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__strlen_avx2 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strlen-avx2.S:65
65  ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strlen-avx2.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) backtrace
#0  __strlen_avx2 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strlen-avx2.S:65
#1  0x00007ffff7e48464 in __GI__IO_puts (str=0x47 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x47>) at ioputs.c:35
#2  0x00005555555553ea in main () at MajorScaleNotes.c:37
(gdb) frame 2
#2  0x00005555555553ea in main () at MajorScaleNotes.c:37
37      printf("%s\n",notes[i]);
(gdb) print notes[i]
$1 = 0x47 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x47>
(gdb)
```

Comment: See my recent answer for this program: [using strcmp in order to compare user input character array with an array of s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72653467)

Comment: `t` and `j` are unused. Please only put relevant code in the question.

Comment: FYI `else;` is not needed.

Comment: Main purpose of running in a debugger is to step through the code and inspect variables. Or run the program until the crash happens and then inspect variables. This main part seems to be missing in your debugger use.

Comment: Oh wow this was a segmentation error due to being out of bounds(thanks xing), sorry for the bad formatting guys ill pay special attention to work on better coding format habits. I assigned "j" as a way to save the value of "i" before it reached the value of 12! Thanks again all.

Comment: Well, you already have `notePosition` for that purpose. You just need to define it in a wider scope to make it visible after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

A few issues ...

1. After the loop, `i` is 12. This is one *beyond* the end of the array, so the final `printf` has UB (undefined behavior). This can produce a segfault.
2. `else;` does nothing.
3. Once a match is found, there is no need to loop further, so we can add a `break` to exit the loop early.

---

Here is the corrected code. It is annotated with the bugs and fixes:

```
/* This is the code for running the Major scale program. The debugging using
gdb is shown after the code. I am new to using pointers and allocating memory
and what not */

// This is a program to generate a major scale based upon user input in C
// programming using formula WS WS HS WS WS WS

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main(void)
{

    int j = 0;
    int i = 0;
    // This tells you which turn you are on on turns 0,1,3,4,5,6 i will be
    // added by 2 and on turn 2 i will be added by 1
    int t = 0;

    char *notes[12] = {
        "A", "A#", "B", "C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#"
    };

    char pickedNote[100];

    for (i = 0; i < 12; ++i) {
        printf("Your notes are  %s\n", notes[i]);
    }

    printf("Please type in a note\n");
    fgets(pickedNote, sizeof(pickedNote), stdin);
    pickedNote[strcspn(pickedNote, "\n")] = 0;
    printf("Your note is %s\n", pickedNote);

// NOTE/FIX: we want this accessible _after_ the loop
#if 1
    int notePosition = -1;
#endif

    for (i = 0; i < 12; ++i) {
        int notePositionTester = (strcmp(pickedNote, notes[i]) == 0);

        if (notePositionTester == 1) {
// NOTE/BUG: we want this to be at an outer scope
#if 0
            int notePosition = i;
#else
            notePosition = i;
#endif

            printf("Your note is in position %d\n", notePosition);

// NOTE/FIX: no need to loop further -- we've found the result
#if 1
            break;
#endif
        }
    }

// NOTE/BUG: as this point, i is 12 which is one _beyond_ the end of the
// array
#if 0
    printf("%s\n", notes[i]);
#else
    if (notePosition >= 0)
        printf("%s\n", notes[notePosition]);
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

---

In the above code, I've used `cpp` conditionals to denote old vs. new code:

```
#if 0
// old code
#else
// new code
#endif

#if 1
// new code
#endif
```

---

Here is the cleaned up code (run through `unifdef -k` with the NOTE comments removed):

```
/* This is the code for running the Major scale program. The debugging using
gdb is shown after the code. I am new to using pointers and allocating memory
and what not */

// This is a program to generate a major scale based upon user input in C
// programming using formula WS WS HS WS WS WS

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main(void)
{

    int j = 0;
    int i = 0;
    // This tells you which turn you are on on turns 0,1,3,4,5,6 i will be
    // added by 2 and on turn 2 i will be added by 1
    int t = 0;

    char *notes[12] = {
        "A", "A#", "B", "C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#"
    };

    char pickedNote[100];

    for (i = 0; i < 12; ++i) {
        printf("Your notes are  %s\n", notes[i]);
    }

    printf("Please type in a note\n");
    fgets(pickedNote, sizeof(pickedNote), stdin);
    pickedNote[strcspn(pickedNote, "\n")] = 0;
    printf("Your note is %s\n", pickedNote);

    int notePosition = -1;

    for (i = 0; i < 12; ++i) {
        int notePositionTester = (strcmp(pickedNote, notes[i]) == 0);

        if (notePositionTester == 1) {
            notePosition = i;

            printf("Your note is in position %d\n", notePosition);

            break;
        }
    }

    if (notePosition >= 0)
        printf("%s\n", notes[notePosition]);

    return 0;
}
```